# Android: How to access item in Fragment in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

In my Activity, I use a Fragment inside a Viewpager. My Fragment include some items like ImageView and ImageButton. Is it possible to access a sepecified items in my fragment ? I want to control this. In my project, I want to set focus to a first ImageButton in Fragment when I press a specified button on the Keyboard ? 
Thx for your help !.

main.xml
..........

```
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerDetail"
                android:layout_width="1170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/motionCotrol"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img"
                    android:layout_width="84dp"
                    android:layout_height="105dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/selection_thick" 
                    />

            </LinearLayout> 
        </RelativeLayout>
```

..........

fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <!--
         <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
         />
    -->

    <include

        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/items" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/items" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/items" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . Create a custom KeyDown event in your fragment class.

```
    public void keyDownInFragment(int keyCode){
      // Your Implementation for focusing a widget goes here
    }
```

2 . In your Activity (FragmentActivity or MainActivity), catch the KeyDown event using the following code,

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Replace the key you have pressed in Keyboard for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME in the following line
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
           // Call your fragment's keydown event method
                  ((FragmentName)fragments.get(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode);
           // get(0) instead of zero user the index number at which you have inserted your fragment in the Page Adapter
        }
    }
```

Comment: thx u, I tried but it does not work! Because I work with a ImageButton in Fragment(in Activty, when i press key on keyboard the ImageButton will set focus). The Fragment i use in Viewpager and i can not work with this Fragment. I can only show Fragment view...

Comment: access your fragment within onKeyDown function like         ((FragmentName)fragments.get(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode); See the update code above

Comment: In my project, I only have one fragment, I set it into a FragmentStatePageAdapter. In my fragment.xml I incluse some items (ImageButton). Now I want to work with the first items on the fragment ( I want to set focus when I press key on Keyboard). How could I do ? ( I can only show the view of the fragment but i cannot work with it )